# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException in external library/jar

Tags: java, ejb, jndi, websphere-liberty

i get a javax.naming.NameNotFoundException in my application which is deployed on a liberty server:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: java:app/ExternalEJB/EJBBean!com.example.server.ejb.SecurityEJB
    at com.ibm.ws.jndi.url.contexts.javacolon.internal.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:355)
    at com.ibm.ws.jndi.url.contexts.javacolon.internal.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:370)
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:428)
    at com.example.connect.server.ServiceProvider.getLocal(ServiceProvider.java:153)
    at com.example.connect.server.ServiceProvider.getLocal(ServiceProvider.java:122)
    at com.example.connect.server.ServiceProvider.getService(ServiceProvider.java:73)
    at com.example.connect.ConnectFactory.makeService(ConnectFactory.java:300)
    at com.example.connect.ConnectFactory.getService(ConnectFactory.java:280)
    at com.example.connect.ConnectFactory.getService(ConnectFactory.java:252)
    at com.example.server.ejb.EJBWrapper.getService(EJBWrapper.java:91)
    at com.example.server.ejb.EJBWrapper.find(EJBWrapper.java:1231)
    at com.example.server.bo.PersonBO.find(PersonBO.java:233)
    at de.example.framework.Wrapper.find(Wrapper.java:102)
```

The application structure is as follows:

```
Appl.ear
|
├──Module1.war (de.example.framework)
├──Module2.war
├──EJBModule.war
|
└───/lib
    ├───ExternalLib.jar (com.example.server)
    |   └── ExternalEJB (EJBBean implements SecurityEJB)
    |
    ├───ExternalLib2.jar (com.example.connect)
    |
    └───MyOwnLib.jar (de.example.service)
```

Now i dont know why the jdni name could not be found by the library (these two libraries work together in other projects). Any suggestions what i do wrong?
If you need more informations, i try to provide them to you.

Thanks!

Edit:
Since the libraries are external ones i do not have the source code, although with tool like JD i can show you how they look like:

EJBBean Declaration:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
@Local({SecurityEJB.class})
public class EJBBean extends BaseStatelessSessionBean implements SecurityEJB {
```

getLocal-method:

```
protected static <T> T getLocal(Class<T> cls, String jndiName) throws GenException {
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
      log.debug("class        : " + cls);
      log.debug("jndi         : " + jndiName);
    } 
    Context ctx = null;
    Object local = null;
    try {
      ctx = getContext();
      if (log.isDebugEnabled())
        log.debug("context      : " + ctx); 
      local = ctx.lookup(jndiName); <--- line 153
      if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("local        : " + local);
        log.debug(" class       : " + local.getClass().getName());
        log.debug(" class loader: " + local.getClass().getClassLoader());
      } 
      return (T)local;
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
      throw new GenException(ex);
    } 
  }
```

the SecurityEJB Interface:

```
public interface SecurityEJB extends ICompressible {
  public static final String JNDI_NAME = "java:app/ExternalEJB/EJBBean!" + SecurityEJB.class
    .getName();
```

features in server.xml:

```
<featureManager>
    <feature>javaee-8.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>ejbRemote-3.2</feature>
    <feature>ldapRegistry-3.0</feature>
    <feature>transportSecurity-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>
```

Comment: We do indeed need more information.  Edit your question and show us line 153 of ServiceProvider.java, which is where the stack trace indicates your Context.lookup call resides.  Also show the code for SecurityEJB and the beginning of the declaration of EJBBean (that is, the class declaration and its annotations).  If the EJBs don’t have annotations, we’ll need to see your ejb-jar.xml as well.

Comment: i added the information but as mentioned i do not have the sources of the libraries.

Comment: Also add part of the `server.xml` where you have defined features, and check the `message.log` if beans are correctly bound to JNDI.

Comment: i could not find an entry for the binding of any bean from the .jar-file. Only bindings of  beans from my own module are shown in the log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the Java EE Platform Specification (Deploying a Java EE Application), a module is only considered an EJB module if it is not in the `lib` directory and contains either an `META-INF/ejb-jar.xml` file or an EJB component defining annotation, such as `@Stateless`.

In this example, since the `EJBBean` class is in `lib/ExternalLib.jar`, the `@Stateless` annotation will be ignored. The `ExternalLib.jar` JAR file is not considered to be an EJB module since it is in the `lib` directory.

`ExternalLib.jar` either needs to be moved out of the `lib` directory, or one of the other EJB or WAR modules needs to contain an `ejb-jar.xml` file that declares `EJBBean` to be an EJB. All classes in the `lib` directory may be referenced by EJB and WAR modules, so it is acceptable to declare a class from a lib module as an EJB in the `ejb-jar.xml` file of a WAR or EJB module. Note that the `java:` lookup would use the module name where the `ejb-jar.xml` file is located; never the name of a JAR in the `lib` directory.

Comment: ok, that seems logical. i switched the location of the jar to the root directory. but now i got a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.server.security.gen.SecurityException cause the jar is not in the lib folder anymore and my own library imports some classes of that jar. how can i achieve that? By adding a configuration parameter to the maven ear plugin?